# case 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' for a specific column

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm learning Node.js and MySQL and making this code where all the columns are UNIQUE, which means that if I try to add a value that already exists it's going to return 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'.
I'm trying to make it so that if that error happens to only a column (socialID) it will execute a code.
For that, I'm using a switch statement.
And I can do this:

```
switch (err.code) {
      case 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'
}
```

But this error works for all columns, and I just want it for a column. Something like:

```
switch (err.code) {
      case 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'.socialID
}
```

I know how to make it with ifs and queries, but that would be a lot longer then doing something like this. I don't know how to see which version is MySQL in.
Sorry for the english and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MySQL server will [only provide three pieces of information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-components.html) to the client library in the event of an error: the error code, the SQLSTATE value, and the error message. If you're trying to figure out which column failed, you're just going to have to perform some string parsing, because that's all that the `mysql` library has to go on. Luckily, the error message is always going to be structured the same, so you can probably create a regular expression object for it.